# How can I disable the TOT time out timer of the TM-V71A?

Tags: kenwood, equipment-operation, echolink

I am using the Kenwood TM-V71A as an EchoLink link station.

When I try to play our weekly bulletin, which has a duration longer than 10 minutes, the TOT cuts the transmission short. I do understand that the 10 minute maximum might be a precaution to overheating in the maximum power setting. However, I am transmitting with 10 W only, and would like to be able to transmit our bulletin in full length.

Is there a way to accomplish this with this rig?
More precise: Is it possible to modify the device to work in the intended way?

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions.

First answer is no, page 70 of the manual, the menu option is TOT and default as you've noticed is 10 and the options are 3, 5, or 10 minutes.

Second answer is you could rig up some array of 555s or a microcontroller such that it unkeys for half a second every nine minutes and nobody's going to notice but the rig TOT will reset.

Comment: I am new on this "forum" so I am trying to be careful, but am I expected to flag this as an accepted answer? I mean it is so trivial. I of course have RTFM. This is why I am asking here after all. I am looking for some hacking instructions like the ones available for changing the device for cross band operation.

Comment: @roland Accepting answers is entirely up to your choice. Generally it's what you do when the answer you get is satisfactory and you *aren't looking for a better one*.